# How to exclude a layer in spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I don't want to enable certain layers in `Spacemacs`, and choose not to install them, for example, `python` layer is commented out:

```
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     ;; python
     rust
```

However, every time I opens a python file, it asks me

```
Support for python-mode requires installation of layer python, do you want to install it? (y or n) n [2 times]
```

I have to keep rejecting it, which is kind of annoying.

Is there a way to exclude those layers and mute such notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this too (the python layer was annoying me too haha).

Changing these settings in my `.spacemacs` got it to quiet down:

```
   dotspacemacs-enable-lazy-installation nil
   dotspacemacs-ask-for-lazy-installation nil
```

Comment: sry, I added
```  (setq dotspacemacs-enable-lazy-installation nil)
  (setq dotspacemacs-ask-for-lazy-installation nil)
```
to dotspacemacs/user-config, and now things are even worse:
python layer is installed without even asking me .

Comment: I think adding those settings in `user-config` could be the issue. They should be in `dotspacemacs/layers` in the default `.spacemacs`, just edit the default values of them to `nil`.